# Emitting only active route's method

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a footer connected on 2 pages. The variables used in footer are defined in store in Vuex. The method emitted from the footer, makes method on both page active. Is there any way to stop the other page's method to work.

**Footer.vue**

```
template:

<div class="text-center">
      <button :class="classFirst" @click="prevPage" :disabled="pageNumber==1" aria-hidden="true"></button>

      <span class="text-white pl-2 pr-2">Page {{pageNumber}} of {{pageCount}}</span>
      <span class="text-white">|</span>

      <button :class="classLast" @click="nextPage"
          :disabled="pageNumber  >= pageCount - 1" aria-hidden="true"></button>
    </div>

......
  computed: {

    pageCount(){
      return store.state.orderPageCount
    },
    pageNumber(){
      return store.state.orderPageNumber
    }
  },

......
  methods: {

    prevPage(){
      let page = this.pageNumber-1;
      bus.$emit("fetchOrders", {page});
    },

    nextPage(){
      let page = this.pageNumber+1;
      bus.$emit("fetchOrders", {page});
    }
  }
```

**Page1.vue**

```
methods: {
    fetchOrders(page) {
      let url = domain + "order";
      if (!page) {
        page = 1;
      }
      this.disable = true;
      axios
        .get(url,{
          params: {
             status:5
          }
         })
        .then(res => {
          let ordersList = [];
          res.data.data.forEach(doc => {
            store.dispatch("patchorderPageCount", res.data.last_page);
            store.dispatch("patchorderPageNumber", res.data.current_page);
          });
        });
    }
  }
```

**Page2.vue**

```
methods: {
    fetchOrders(page) {
      let url = domain + "order";
      if (!page) {
        page = 1;
      }
      this.disable = true;
      axios
        .get(url,{
          params: {
             status:4
          }
         })
        .then(res => {
          let ordersList = [];
          res.data.data.forEach(doc => {
            store.dispatch("patchorderPageCount", res.data.last_page);
            store.dispatch("patchorderPageNumber", res.data.current_page);
          });
        });
    }
  }
```

When using footer in page2, the method of page1 also works.
Is there are way to emit only that method which page is active.

Sorry if it's hard to get what is being asked and thankyou for help!

Comment: Why don't you move `fetchOrders` to Footer.vue?

Comment: Because it have different data coming on both pages

Comment: It does not matter, just make `status` a parameter of `fetchOrders`. In the end the dispatch the same actions with the same result. If that don't help you, move `prevPage` and `nextpage` to Page1 and Page2. If it starts getting messy, that means you should use Vuex actions.